# "Open with" for multiple music files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu, music

**The problem:**

I'm wanting to select and open multiple music files; doing this effectively queues them all allowing me to skip and shuffle through them, which playing each file individually wouldn't allow me to do. However, I need to play these music files in separate, non-default music players, and the only way to easily do this is by using the `Open With` context menu entry; the context menu entry which, in Windows 7, is famously no longer existent for multiple files.

Therefore, I'm looking for a solution that will enable the `Open With` context menu entry when right-clicking multiple files, and allow me to select the program that I want to use to open those files. I can't imagine this is a hard thing to do with Regedit, but previous research has just brought up workarounds like [opening files in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1113578/open-with-on-multiple-files) and [using the `Edit` context menu entry in the case of images](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/windows-7-open-with-function-disappears-for-multiple-files/).

So, is there actually any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

My way is to use the "Send To" context menu:

[image: SendTo Context Menu]

Create shortcuts to each audio application's executable file (e.g. for VLC you'd create a shortcut to `vlc.exe`) and put the shortcuts into this folder:

`C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\`

Now you can select multiple files and "send" them to the audio app of your choice.