# How do I get rid of an extra www. in a specific web address?

Tags: windows, website

When I type in a specific web address my browser automatically adds another `www.` in front of it. So the address ends up looking like this:

`www.www.example.net`

How do I get this to stop? I have Windows 10.

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it happen in other browsers too?

Comment: dont type www, just type lovebetterlife.com. I haven't typed www in over 10 years.

Comment: @Moab Not every website will adhire to not using www. I don't do it often, but I've found a few where it doesn't work without

Comment: I have lived without it for a long time.

Comment: Any web address or there is one in particular with this problem? If it is only one particular address that gives you this problem and virtually no other, then chances are, this is some redirection bug in the web site pointed by that address.

Answer (score 13):

**Internet Explorer**

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Internet Options
3. General tab
4. Appearance
5. Languages button.
6. In the new box which opens, **check** the Do not add www to the beginning of typed addresses.
7. Click OK/Apply and exit.

**Google Chrome**

1. Go to Settings
2. Show advanced settings
3. **Uncheck** the box saying Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar or the app launcher search box.

**Firefox**

1. Open Firefox
2. type `about:config` in the address bar and hit **Enter**.
3. Search for **browser.fixup.alternate**.
4. Now double-click on **browser.fixup.alternate.enabled** to **change its value to False**. The other two settings are there, if you want to change the default values of the prefix and suffix.

Hope this will fix your issue :)

Comment: If none of this work, maybe you want to backup your browser favorites and reset IE, reset Chrome or reset Firefox  as the case may be, and see if that works for you.

Comment: This is a good answer, so +1, but it may have helped if you first asked what browser he is using, rather than just assume a few and write a full answer for 3 most used browsers. Given he is using windows 10, chances are high he is using Edge browser.

Comment: Atlas, so really you cheated yourself out of +1 on each of these sections as a separate answer in other words.... If you could type them out quick enough at least. Then someone like me would come along and see answer #1 and give you +1 and then see answer #2 and give you +1 again, and so forth. But it is not a "rule" as far as I know but it is a "strategy" you could utilize to capitalize on maximum reputation for good answers (or just put it all in one answer if you wish).

Comment: As a matter of fact, check out what I did here: https://superuser.com/questions/1113578/open-with-on-multiple-files one time to give you an example.... LOL

Comment: Atlas_Gondal : Good answer.  Since poster failed to mention which browser, you provided a bunch of information which is most likely to be useful.  That is likely more useful than asking a question and providing no useful information until the question is answered.  Good job on taking the initiative.  (Hopefully if the asker is using a different browser, that person will have enough sense to provide a clarification.)  @LPChip: I respectfully disagree, for reasons just provided.  Oh, and by the way, regarding what "he" is using, I say 80%+ chance this poster was female.  :)

Comment: Great example and explanation @McDonald's, I missed chance to earn more reputation... LOL Thanks both for appreciation!

Comment: @LPChip: I agree with TOOGAM. It is widely considered (and, I believe, documented somewhere) that the #1 objective of [SU] (and [SE] in general) is to build a knowledge base that will be useful to many people. Helping the current OP is nice, but it’s a secondary objective. Yes, it would have been good if Atlas_Gondal had determined what browser the OP was using, so he could be sure to *include* that browser in his answer — but providing a multi-faceted answer, that promises to help many people in the future, was the right thing to do.

Comment: @Atlas_Gondal: See the above.  And don’t take [what “McDonald's” says](/q/1220315/150988#comment1783748_1220318) seriously.  When you have multiple *different* answers to a question, using different approaches and/or techniques, you should post them as separate answers, so people can vote on them independently (e.g., vote one up and the others down) and we can get a ranking of their quality.  But, if you were to take a solution like this and post it as three separate answers, people would believe that you were gaming the system to get more reputation, and they might downvote you just for that.

Comment: I think, it would be better if I do; what I think is right and even better to take help from docs. Because everyone has his/her own rules which may or may not be liked by others.