# Do a context menu action for multiple selected files in the Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, context-menu, regedit

I'd like to create a Windows Explorer context menu action for **multiple selected files**.

I created a key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MyAction\command` with a string value

```
C:\python37\python.exe "c:\test\test.py" "%1"
```

This script only displays the command-line arguments for now (for debugging purpose): `import sys; print(sys.argv); input()`

When I select **two files** `a.txt`, `b.txt` in the Explorer, and right click on "MyAction", then:

- I'd like to have this script called **once**, and the command-line arguments passed to Python should be

  ```
  ["c:\test\test.py", "c:\a.txt", "c:\b.txt"]
  ```
- instead I get this script called **twice** (once independently for each file), and the command-line arguments passed are:

  ```
  ["c:\test\test.py", "c:\a.txt"]
  ["c:\test\test.py", "c:\b.txt"]
  ```

**How to make a context menu action call the command only once when 2 files are selected, with the 2 files as command-line arguments?**

---

**TL;DR** I would like this to be launched:

```
C:\python37\python.exe "c:\test\test.py" "a.txt" "b.raw" "file_with_noext"
```

and not:

```
C:\python37\python.exe "c:\test\test.py" "a.txt"
C:\python37\python.exe "c:\test\test.py" "b.raw"
C:\python37\python.exe "c:\test\test.py" "file_with_noext"
```

when using the context menu action on multiple files.

---

Note: [Open With on multiple files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1113578/open-with-on-multiple-files) and its answers don't solve it; I tried with `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\*\shell\MyAction\command` but this menu item doesn't appear when I select multiple files (let's say `a.txt`, `b.raw`, `file_with_noext`, and `testdir\`).

Comment: Thank you @DavidPostill for your link, but I think the duplicate flag is a little mistake here. This other question shows how to have a new context menu item (such as "Open with") for multiple files ; whereas my question is : how to have a context menu item on multiple files **that triggers the launch of the process only once**, with `"%1"` being *the list* of all files in one pass. Thus, this question is really different. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'll reopen, but the accepted answer on the duplicate *should* work. It does for Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. I forgot to mention it's for Windows 7, I just added this in the tags. Also, which key would you use to be able to select files of different ext or directories, in replacement of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Open With\command`?

Comment: No idea :/ ....

Comment: Maybe the answer there is good for your question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088510/implement-explorer-contextmenu-and-pass-multiple-files-to-one-program-instance

Comment: Thanks @Gazeld, this is interesting indeed!

Comment: For that matter, it seems that it opens the command *simultaneously* for all selected files, instead of in a serial manner... which is kind of horrible if you are trying to do some operation on, say, a flash drive which has limited bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies if you got the answer already but I think the only way to do this is to place a shortcut to your app in the SendTo folder (You can open it from a Run window by typing shell:sendto) and then highlighting both files and choosing your program from the "Send to" context menu.

Answer (score 2):

I created a small program that completely solves this problem.
https://github.com/ge9/ExecuteCommand-Pipe

It is based on this Microsoft sample code: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/ExecuteCommandVerb

It uses COM (Component Object Model) technology of Windows, so there are no restriction on the number or path length of passed files. Also it doesn't involve any inter-process communication, preserving the order of files.
The command for opening files is specified in registry values.
See the repository for details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### SUMMARY

1. In Registry put the target program as **Context Menu Create File.exe** which writes **reg.txt** file.
2. In your main program loop every 1 second to check if **reg.txt** exists. If it exists, kill the **Context Menu Create File.exe** and delete the **reg.txt** file. Then copy the selected file paths and manipulate with them.
3. If your program loops to check for **reg.txt**, then you need to start the program before executing context menu either on startup or manually.

> I did this with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com).
>
> These 2 AutoHotkey scripts below allow you to add a `Open With Chrome` context menu item in Windows Explorer to open multiple selected files.
>
> You can leave all variable values as they are, but if you want to change the `contextMenu` value and `program` name then see **3.1.**

### INSTRUCTIONS:

Create 2 files in the same directory:

1. Create 1st program **Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk**

   1. `RunAsAdmin` Label ensures that the script runs as admin (fixes adding Registry values).

      1. The `If (!A_IsAdmin)` checks if current user is **NOT** admin, A_IsAdmin is a built in AutoHotkey variable that returns 1 if user is admin, 0 otherwise.
      2. `Run, \*RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"` ***RunAs** parameter runs the script as admin, **"%A_ScriptFullPath%"** gets the full path of the current executing script.
      3. `ExitApp` exits the current script instance running without admin privileges.
      4. Because the `Run` command runs the script again with admin privileges it will skip the `IF` condition and continue executing code below.
   2. `ContextMenuCreateFile:`  Label creates a **Context Menu Create File.exe** which creates a file **reg.txt** and exits **Context Menu Create File.exe** after it has written the file **reg.txt**. Make sure you specify where your `Ahk2Exe.exe` path is in the `RunWait` command.
   3. `Add To Context Menu:`  Label adds the Registry entry which runs **Context Menu Create File.exe**.

      1. Set the `contextMenu` variable to what needs to be displayed in the Context Menu. (The `program` name is set to `contextMenu`)
      2. Set the `regPath` to your desired Registry path.
      3. When it executes the `MsgBox`, check if the command is added to the Registry in the address bar.
   4. `CreateStartupShortcut:` Label creates the shortcut of the main program **Open With Chrome.exe** in Startup folder.

### Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk

```
; =============Recommended Settings=============
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
; =============Recommended Settings=============

AddToContextMenuAndCreateStartupShortcut:
RunAsAdmin:  ; =============RunAsAdmin=============
If (!A_IsAdmin)  ; IF NOT Admin
{
    Run, *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run script as admin
    ExitApp  ; Exit the current instance running without admin privileges
}
ContextMenuCreateFile:  ; =============ContextMenuCreateFile=============
contextMenuCreateFileAhk := 
(LTrim
"#NoEnv
#NoTrayIcon
#SingleInstance Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1

ContextMenuCreateFile:
FileDelete, reg.txt
FileAppend, , reg.txt
ExitApp
Return"
)  ; contextMenuCreateFileAhk
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.exe  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.exe
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.ahk
FileAppend, %contextMenuCreateFileAhk%, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; MAKE Context Menu Create File.ahk
RunWait, C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe /in "Context Menu Create File.ahk" /out "Context Menu Create File.exe"  ; Convert AHK to EXE
FileDelete, Context Menu Create File.ahk  ; DEL Context Menu Create File.ahk
AddToContextMenu:  ; =============AddToContextMenu=============
path := ""  ; path
program := "Context Menu Create File"  ; program
contextMenu := "Open With Chrome"  ; contextMenu
regPath := "HKCR\*\shell"  ; regPath
StringReplace, regKey, contextMenu, %A_Space%, , A  ; regKey
regKey := 0 regKey  ; regKey
Loop, Files, %program%.exe, F  ; Find Program.exe In Current Dir
{
    path := A_LoopFileLongPath  ; Set Program Path
}
cmd := 
(LTrim
"reg add """ regPath "\" regKey """ /ve /t REG_SZ /d """ contextMenu """ /f
reg add """ regPath "\" regKey "\command"" /ve /t REG_SZ /d ""\""" path "\""`"" /f"
)  ; Registry
FileDelete, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; CREATE Add To Context Menu.bat
FileAppend, %cmd%, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; CREATE Add To Context Menu.bat
RunWait, Add To Context Menu.bat, , Hide  ; RUN Add To Context Menu.bat (*RunAs ADMIN)
FileDelete, Add To Context Menu.bat  ; DEL Add To Context Menu.bat
Run, regedit  ; regedit
WinWait, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; Registry
Sleep, 333
ControlSetText, Edit1, %regPath%\%regKey%\command, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlFocus, Edit1, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, Edit1, {Enter}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, SysListView321, {Control Down}{NumpadAdd}{Control Up}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
ControlSend, SysListView321, {F5}, Registry Editor ahk_class RegEdit_RegEdit ahk_exe regedit.exe  ; regPath
MsgBox, 262192, CHECK, Check If Added %contextMenu% To Registry  ; CHECK
CreateStartupShortcut:  ; =============CreateStartupShortcut=============
path := ""  ; path
program := contextMenu  ; program
Loop, Files, %program%.exe, F  ; Find Program.exe In Current Dir
{
    path := A_LoopFileLongPath  ; Set Program Path
}
FileCreateShortcut, %path%, %A_Startup%\%program%.lnk  ; Create Startup Shortcut
Run, %A_Startup%, , Max  ; Check If Shortcut Created
Run, "%program%.exe"  ; Run Program
MsgBox, 262144, CHECK, Check If Shortcut Created  ; CHECK
ExitApp  ; ExitApp
Return
```

2. Create 2nd program **Open With Chrome.ahk** which is the main program.

   1. Here a `Loop` is created and checks every 1 second if **reg.txt** exists.
   2. `IfExist, reg.txt` it kills the **Context Menu Create File.exe** and deletes the **reg.txt**.
   3. Then it activates explorer.exe window and copies all selected file paths to **CLIPBOARD**.
   4. `If CLIPBOARD contains .,\` to make sure **CLIPBOARD** contains path **"\"** with extension **"."**.
   5. The list of selected files is saved in `selectedFiles` variable.
   6. The Loop below `chromeParams := ""` loops through selected files, gets the `filePath`s and surrounds them with double quotes, and `StringReplace` replaces the Windows path as url file path ex: `C:\path\file.jpg` to `file:///path/file.jpg`.
   7. Then the `filePath` is concatenated to `chromeParams`.
   8. `StringTrimRight` removes the last space from `chromeParams` string.
   9. Then `Run, chrome.exe %chromeParams%` is executed with `%chromeParams%` (list of selected files). (If the command doesn't open Chrome then put full path to Chrome, ex: `Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` with the same parameters)

### Open With Chrome.ahk

```
; =============Recommended Settings=============
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
; =============Recommended Settings=============

OpenWithChrome:
Loop  ; Loop Start
{
    Sleep, 1000  ; Fix High CPU
    IfExist, reg.txt  ; IF reg.txt EXIST
    {
        RunWait, cmd /c taskkill /im "Context Menu Create File.exe" /f, , Hide  ; Fix Opening 2 Compose Windows
        FileDelete, reg.txt  ; DEL reg.txt
        WinActivate, ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe  ; Explorer
        CLIPBOARD := ""  ; Clear Clipboard
        Send, {Control Down}{c}{Control Up}  ; Copy File Paths
        ClipWait, 0  ; Clip Wait
        If CLIPBOARD contains .,\  ; IF CLIPBOARD contains .,\
        {
            selectedFiles := CLIPBOARD  ; selectedFiles
            chromeParams := ""  ; chromeParams
            Loop, Parse, selectedFiles, `n, `r  ; Loop Start selectedFiles
            {
                filePath := """file:///" A_LoopField """"  ; filePath
                StringReplace, filePath, filePath, \, /, A  ; Replace \ with /
                chromeParams .= filePath . " "  ; chromeParams .= %filePath%,
            }
            StringTrimRight, chromeParams, chromeParams, 1  ; Remove Last Space
            Run, chrome.exe %chromeParams%  ; Open Files In Chrome
        }
    }
}
Return
```

3. Convert both **Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.ahk** and **Open With Chrome.ahk** to **EXE** files in the same directory using **Ahk2Exe.exe** --> (find in Start Menu, just browse file and hit convert)
4. Execute the **`Add To Context Menu And Create Startup Shortcut.exe`**
5. Select files, right click and the **Open With Chrome** context menu item should appear.