# PowerShell, Pass multiple files and folders to a PowerShell script via a SendTo shortcut

Tags: powershell, windows-explorer, context-menu, command-line-arguments, send-to

I would like to have a shortcut in SendTo that points to a PowerShell script such that all selected items in File Explorer are passed to the PowerShell script as arguments. This would be extremely useful for me to be able to define custom tasks in PowerShell.

e.g. If I have a shortcut `Zip to backup folder.lnk` in SendTo. I select multiple items (files and folders) in File Explorer then right-click > SendTo > 'Zip to backup folder', all of the files and folders that I selected are then passed as arguments to the PowerShell script (as `.fullname` paths is maybe easiest) from where I can perform multiple PowerShell operations on the selected items.

How can I setup a shortcut in `shell:SendTo` that can pass the selected File Explorer items to a PowerShell script?

I see some things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932881/invoking-powershell-command-from-windows-explorer-send-to-menu/15934981#15934981) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1563715/do-a-context-menu-action-for-multiple-selected-files-in-the-windows-explorer), but one is a cludge with Cmd (a pure PowerShell method is probably more appropriate in 2022) and one is more about full context menu items.

Comment: First thing you want to modify your script to handle the file being passed in. In powershell, anything that gets passed in can be referenced with `$args[0]`. Next, when you save your script and set it to run in the registry for a right click menu, you'll want the value of the menu item to be `myscript.ps1 "%1"` .  %1 automatically passes the current selected file/files object to the program as $args

Comment: Good point, yes, I can split up the input files/folders with `$args[0]`. I don't think registry is required, as `shell:SendTo` is just a folder where we can drop shortcuts, so can't we just have a shortcut in there that points to a PowerShell without having to access the registry? No problem if I have to update the registry though, happy to do anything that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut in your "SendTo" folder can have this target:

- for Windows PowerShell:

  ```text
  "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -File "FullPathToYourScript.ps1"
  ```
- for PowerShell 7+:

  ```text
  "%ProgramFiles%\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -File "FullPathToYourScript.ps1"
  ```

When the "Send to" menu item is invoked, the system appends the full paths of the selected files to the command. In the script, use the automatic `$args` array variable to get the file paths.

An example of how you can get the number of selected files and
loop over the paths:

```sh
"Received $($args.Count) files:"

foreach( $path in $args ) {
    "Processing file: $path"    
}
```

Source :
[Pass the names of the selected files from "Send To" menu to powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647009/pass-the-names-of-the-selected-files-from-send-to-menu-to-powershell-script).

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I need, many thanks, I can build anything from this start point. I had not come across that other answer, thanks for sharing it here.